# Difference between "%i" and "%d"

Tags: c, hex, scanf, octal, conversion-specifier

What is the difference between `"%i"` and `"%d"` in the `scanf` function, are they same or different? In `printf`, `"%d"` is used to print an integer value, so is the use of `"%i"`.

Comment: Perhaps a reference [like this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) could be useful to read.

Comment: They're the same for `printf`, but different for `scanf`.  There's almost no use for `%i` with `printf`, but it's useful for `scanf`, because it means "read any base".

Comment: https://ideone.com/pvr5E5

Answer (score 4):

With `printf`, you always want to specify the base to print in.  So `%d` prints in decimal, and `%x` prints in hexadecimal, and `%o` prints in octal (base 8).

The formats for `scanf` generally mirror `printf`.  So `%d` reads decimal, and `%x` reads hexadecimal, and `%o` reads octal.

Now, in a C source file, you can use any of the three bases, with a prefix indicating your choice: a leading `0x` indicates hexadecimal, and a leading `0` indicates octal.  That's for the C compiler reading  C source files, but somebody realized it'd be nice if your program had the ability to read input in any base at run time.  So, for example, the `strtol` function is normally told (via its third argument) exactly what base to accept, but if you give it a third argument of 0, it intuits the base based on a prefix, just like the compiler does.

Now we get to `%i`.  Someone decided it'd be nice to give `scanf` the ability to read any base, just like `strtol` does.  So that's what `%i` does: it, well, reads any base, paying attention to a leading `0` or `0x` prefix, just like `strtol` does.

But then, finally, since it's nice if `printf` and `scanf` formats mirror each other, someone decided it would be good if `printf` accepted `%i` also.  In a way it's meaningless: you obviously can't intuit an *output* format the same way you can an input format.  So for `printf`, `%i` always means decimal, just like `%d`.  So it's redundant and unnecessary, but I've noticed that more and more of the questions asked here on SO seem to use it, so someone out there most be teaching new programmers to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The format specification `%i` opposite to the conversion specification `%d` used in the family of functions like `scanf` can interpret the input as an octal number if it starts from `0` or as hexadecimal number if it is preceded by the hexadecimal suffix `0x` or `0X`.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> **i** Matches an optionally signed integer, whose format is the same as
> expected for the subject sequence of the **strtol function with the
> value 0 for the base argument**. The corresponding argument shall be a
> pointer to signed integer.

and (7.22.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions)

> 3 **If the value of base is zero, the expected form of the subject
> sequence is that of an integer constant as described in 6.4.4.1**,
> optionally preceded by a plus or minus sign, but not including an
> integer suffix.

And integer constants are

```
(6.4.4.1) integer-constant:
    decimal-constant integer-suffixopt
    octal-constant integer-suffixopt
    hexadecimal-constant integer-suffixopt

(6.4.4.1) decimal-constant:
    nonzero-digit
    decimal-constant digit
(6.4.4.1) octal-constant:
    0
    octal-constant octal-digit
(6.4.4.1) hexadecimal-constant:
    hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit
    hexadecimal-constant hexadecimal-digit
(6.4.4.1) hexadecimal-prefix: one of
    0x 0X
```